# Front end Java, back end C++ , how to join?

Tags: java, c++

Lets give an over-basic example, I have a program which goes through a directory and grabs the list of files in the directory. Assume for argument's sake that this HAS to be done in C++. I then wish to present the list of files using Java Swing?

How is this done?

Comment: Mixing Java and any other language (that does not compile down to JVM bytecode anyway) is heretical. It must all be pure Java lest the cooties consume you, or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have your C++ program write to Stdout and then your Java program can read from that. You could then have your Java front end execute your C++ back-end and then read the results.

[This Article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) is a good source of information on how to consume stdout/stderr.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it through the [Java Native Interface (JNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).  Oracle has an [official guide](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/), but you'll probably find it easier to google for tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

one basic method would be storing the c++ output in a text file and reading it from java.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ program puts the list in a specific file, and the Java program reads that file?
Another way might be to use sockets (I don't know Java well enough to know its IPC possibilities) to communicate between the programs "live".

In the end, if you have to use both C++ and Swing, then you can not do it in one single program.

Comment: +1 to use Sockets. I always prefer this method. It can be instantaneous and synchronization is easy. You can have the Java program use a TCP socket for listening, then the C++ program can connect to that port and send the TCP message.

Comment: *...you can not do it in one single program* unless you use JNI

Answer (score 0):

Use Java Native Interface (JNI) as Kevin suggested.  Or, if you need to have a process boundary between Java & C++, you'll need to serialize objects from the process running C++ code to the JVM process.

Also you may find some use in this [Dr. Dobb's article from 1998](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184410632).