# Is there a way to call a Java class from a Visual Studio Windows Forms Application?

Tags: java, vb.net, visual-studio

I mainly program in Java, but I often do GUI things on Visual Studio. I have written a program in Java that is fairly comprehensive and long, and I do not know how to rewrite it in Visual Basic. Is there any way I can call methods or create objects in Visual Basic that is based off of a Java class, or are there other ways I can implement or import Java snippets into Visual Studio?

I saw something like this, and I'm not sure how it works:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
 Set x = CreateObject("MyTest")
 MsgBox x.myfunction(500, 500)
End Sub
```

I saw some information on "bridges," but my goal is to do things just on my PC and not on the cloud.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252296/front-end-java-back-end-c-how-to-join seems like a similar situation.  The front end is Java, the back end c++.

Comment: Probably with a Web Service exposed from the Java Project.

Comment: Can't you use Java swing for the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, you're probably going to have to spend a lot of time working with JNI and P/Invoke (or whatever .NET's native interfaces are these days) to get Java code talking natively with managed code on .NET in the same process. You're better off just wrapping your Java code with Spring Boot and calling it as a service.